# Multiply cell value depending on keyword

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to apply a transformation to a table which basically looks like this:

If there is a certain keyword in column A, then the number in column B should be multiplied by 2.

Is that possible with google spreadsheets? if so, how?

Comment: You could put the calculated value into a new column, but updating the same column is problematic because the cell would continually multiply by 2 when the condition was true due to referencing itself.  A script could do this if a new column is out of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following formula to the cell C1, and fill down as necessary

`=IF(A1="keyword",B1*2,B1)`

**References**
[IF - Google Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this for multiple values across the board down the entire column for automation purposes, you can also use the following formula:

```
=IF(
OR(A:A = "Keyword 1", A:A = "Keyword 2"), 
B:B*2, 
           IF(A:A = "Keyword 3", 
               B*B*3,
               ))
```